# questions - flag for closing if question is trivial?

Tags: support

I came across this question just now:

[How to run a bash script via absolute path?](https://superuser.com/questions/1067609/how-to-run-a-bash-script-via-absolute-path)

This question is extremely trivial, it's like [RTFM or STFW level](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Frankly, such questions should not be asked at all, and waste people's time. I looked to flag this question for closure, but I didn't find anything suitable in the reasons for "Should be closed...". It's not off-topic(strictly), it's not too broad, it doesn't really belong on another site, nothing.

What do the rules say to do with such questions? Is there any specific reason we can use to 'deal with' those?

Comment: "but I didn't find anything suitable in the reasons" - Which is an indication that the question is on topic, it might be a bad question, so issue a down vote to indicate precisely that.  *A bad question can be on topic.*

Comment: Related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7082/where-do-you-draw-the-line-between-a-stupid-question-and-an-acceptable-one

Answer (score 3):

Not everything is trivial for everyone. Don't forget, one of the problems we try to solve is documentation often sucks.

If its a lack of research effort, maybe a downvote, but that question looks like the sort of thing that would be useful for someone else.

I'd note, crappy answers don't get a pass, especially when the current answers are pretty good ;).

Comment: `documentation often sucks.` True.

Comment: "the current answers are pretty good" - thanks for the compliment ;)

Answer (score 2):

**No, it should not be closed.** Closing is for questions that are off-topic, unspecific, or otherwise unfit for our Q&A format.

If it's really not a useful question, you should **downvote** it. Let's see what the downvote button's tooltip says:

> This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful

Of course, if you can find a question that it's a duplicate of, you can flag/vote to close it as such.

Comment: I did downvote; I just feel it's just going to attract basic answers such as 'that's not how it works', or 'did you read the documentation?'

Comment: @cst1992 - If it does downvote those answers, leave a comment that our expectations of an answer, are higher then whatever they said.  *The current answers to that question don't have that problem though.*